# When I put "Logout" button,Page not found error happens

Tags: python, html, django

When I click "Logout" button,Page not found error is raised.

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/top.html')
```

in index.html

```
<div class="container">
        <ul class="top-menu">
            <form name="logout" method="post" action="{% url 'accounts:logout_view' %}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="color:white;background-color: #F62459;border-style: none;">Logout</button>
            <input name="next" type="hidden"/>
            </form>
        </ul>
</div>
```

But I put Logout button,Page not found (404) error happens.Traceback is

Page not found (404)Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/static/accounts/logout_view

My ideal system is when I put logout button, it sends top.html.

project tree

```
accounts
|migrations
|static
|templates
  |registration
  |accounts
    |base.html
    |detail.html
```

What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

urls.py is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^top$', views.top,name='top'),
    url(r'^detail$', views.detail,name='detail'),
    url(r'^login/$', login,
        {'template_name': 'registration/accounts/login.html'},
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
]
```

Comment: The name given in `{% url 'accounts:logout_view' %}` depends on your `urls.py` file. Pleas include this file in your answer.

Comment: @PacoH. I added urls.py.Id u know something, please help me

Comment: Try `{% url 'accounts:logout' %}` as that is your URL name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You name the logout url 'logout':

```
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
```

Therefore you should also refer to it as 'logout' when reversing the url:

```
<form name="logout" method="post" action="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">
```